# Self-hosted Service for Software/Firmware distribution

Tags: cms, self-hosted

I'm responsible for distribute Software/Firmware to our technicians. Currently i use Seafile with RO for them because of sync fucntion.

But i would change the system to some Webapplication where i can upload and manage the Versions and Releasenotes of the SW/FW. Self hosting is mandatory because our ITSEC doesn't allow external hoster for SW/FW.

Someone know such an Tool? Open Source is welcome...

i have already searched on some Wordpress plugins and other stuff but without success.